# Annoying Android - RSS problem

Tags: android, database, image-processing, rss

I'm struggling big time with a stupid problem which i can't seem to fix.
Basicly what i do in my application is the following:

I download all the RSS content to a local database, including the enclosure of every feed (images) but not every feed contains an image.

about 10 of the 100 feeds don't contain an image
What happens with the feeds that don't contain an image is shown in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTUBl.png

The feeds with no image get the image of the previouse feed for some reason...

I'll place all my code below in hope someone can tell me what in the world i'm doing wrong...

This part is where i download the image to the local storage, this function works correctly however for some reason the feed with no enclosure gets the enclosure of the previouse feed send back to it...

```
for (Message msg : wildLife){

                String imageURL = msg.getEnclosure();
                String imageName = imageURL.substring(imageURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
                String imagePath = ImageDir + imageName;

                //-- Call upon the function that will download the image.
                if (imageURL !=null){
                    DownloadFromUrl(imageURL, imagePath);
                }               

                //-- We add all rows we find in the rrs feed to our local stored database.
                db.addWildlifeRow(
                    msg.getTitle(),
                    msg.getDescription(),
                    "Empty slot",
                    imagePath,
                    msg.getLink());
            }
```

I checked in the RSS parser and it doesn't store the same URL twice. So no problem there. It goes wrong (for as far as i know) when requisting the URL enclosure from a message item.

Is there anyone who might have encountered this same problem?

All advice is welcome i've been stuck in this problem for days now, and i can't seem to figure it out...

If you would require more code to find a possible solution just ask and i will provide it.

P.S. it goes wrong before placing the data into my database, so when reading the info from the message out and placing it in the database, its already gone wrong there. The enclosure is copied from the reviouse one (if there was none)

Regards, joery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //-- Call upon the function that will download the image.
                if (imageURL !=null){
                    DownloadFromUrl(imageURL, imagePath);
                } 
            else
                imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Try adding an else part here and clear any old image in ur imageview

Comment: Mmm, yea thats not it mate, i've tried that, but aparently it always returns a value other then null
it tell me that the else code is "dead"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried walking through it in debug?

I agree that it seems as though

```
String imageURL = msg.getEnclosure();
```

must be always returning something - as if msg.getEnclosure() returned null for items with out an image then you would get NullPointerException on the following line at

```
String imageName = imageURL.substring(imageURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

If you could provide the RSS parsing code that could be useful - I assume other than that there is no other pre-processing of the Wildlife message set?

Comment: Hey rhinds, 

Yea you should be correct about that nullpointer exception. 
So any idea why it returns something, even when there shouldn't be an enclosure with that item?

You can find the code here, aparently my score isn't high enough to make a long message here on stackoverflow

http://pastebin.com/gLyW7S9M

If you need anything else let me know

Comment: can you provide the URL you are trying to parse so we can see the feed xml?

Comment: there are 4 feeds: http://pastebin.com/ESKGaGGz
Every feed is build up correctly.
And the enclosure tag is not included with those 10 feeds, however they still get a enclosure when asking for the enclosure

Comment: Not too sure how the code is iterating through the list of ITEMs in the ITEMLIST (line 8 gets the ITEMLIST and line 10 then just seems to get a single ITEM) - but it could be because the CurrentMessage is Final - it could be that it is not being re-initialised every time - this would mean that normally the fields (title/enclosure/etc) are getting overriden with correct values, but in the case that there is no enclosure you are left with the previous message link - try removing Final from currentMessage in the parse() method?

Comment: The following error occurs when i remove the final declaration:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/XoJjV.png Is it me or is it just not allowed to not use final?

Comment: Yeah, didnt spot that - because you are essentially defining an inner-class when you define the start() method for the StartElementListener (line 21) then to be able to reference the variables from the containing class in the inner class they have to be final.  Try adding on line 12 of the parser: currentMessage.setEnclosure("");    (This should just reset the image for each item)

Comment: enclosure.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {
   public void start(Attributes attributes) {
    currentMessage.setEnclosure("");
    String enclosure = attributes.getValue("url");
    currentMessage.setEnclosure(enclosure);
   }
  });

Nothing changed, still the duplicate images

Comment: don't put it inside the Listener, put it towards the top of the parse() method - try putting it directly after this line: Element itemlist = root.getChild(CHANNEL);

Comment: Bah, nothing seems to work...
I really don't understand why its so hard to just not fill the elemenetn if its empty ...

Comment: Agreed - the implementation does seem pretty clunky - having looked at the source code, the problem seems to be because the getChild() method is actually performing a getOrCreateChild() - really you need a getChild method that returns null so you can determine whether or not the XML element is pressent or not.

Comment: There is a walkthrough (and source code) of another SAX based RSS parser here for Android - not sure that it would exactly match your feed requirement, but at least you could easily modify the implementation for your needs: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-rss-reader-20.html